# Program not printing out all information

Tags: java, json, methods, overloading

I am creating a store front application in Java. I have my main driver program with 5 different classes it is using. I cannot get it to print out my inventory I have listed in my JSON file. What am I doing wrong or what am I missing here? My FileService class is at the bottom from where the driver is calling the method. I think that is where my problem is.

```
package app;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class StoreFront {
    
    static InventoryManager inventoryManager = new InventoryManager();
    static ShoppingCart shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
    static Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
//  static FileService fileService = new FileService();
    
    private static void viewProducts() { 
        inventoryManager.displaySalableProducts();
    }
    
    private static void purchaseProducts() {
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the product you want to purchase: ");
        scnr.nextLine(); // Consume newline character
        String productName = scnr.nextLine();

        SalableProduct productToPurchase = inventoryManager.findProductByName(productName);
        if (productToPurchase == null) {
            System.out.println("Product not found.");
        } else {
            if (productToPurchase.getQty() > 0) {
                shoppingCart.addItem(productToPurchase);
                productToPurchase.setQty(productToPurchase.getQty() - 1);
                System.out.println("Product purchased successfully.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Product is out of stock.");
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    private static void returnProducts() {
        shoppingCart.returnProduct(null);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

/*      
 * old method of manually adding inventory
        inventoryManager.addProduct(new Food("Goji Berry", "bright orange-red berry that comes from a shrub native to Asia", 8.32, 496));
        inventoryManager.addProduct(new Potion("Elixir", "Potion that grants eternal life", 3469.00, 4));
        inventoryManager.addProduct(new Helmet("Kabuto", "Ancient Japanese war helemt", 999.99, 43));
        inventoryManager.addProduct(new Tomahawk("Polished Tomahawk", "Benjamin Martins Tomahawk", 567.00, 1));
        inventoryManager.addProduct(new Shield("Heater Shield", "Used in the Middle Ages by knights and soldiers", 269.00, 57));
        inventoryManager.addProduct(new Sword("Katana", "single-edged sword used by Japanese samurai", 4420.00, 21));
*/      
        inventoryManager.initializeInventoryFromFile("inventory.json");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Game Store \n");
        System.out.println("Please select an option from the menu");
        System.out.println("***************************************");
        System.out.println("************MAIN MENU ******************\n");
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter one of the following:\n\n"+
            "'1' : View Products\n"+
            "'2' : Purchase Products\n"+
            "'3' : Return Products\n"+
            "'4' : Exit");
            
            int menuChoice = scnr.nextInt();
            
            switch(menuChoice) {
            case 1:
                viewProducts();
                break;
            case 2:
                purchaseProducts();
                break;
            case 3:
                returnProducts();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Thank you for coming by. Please come again.");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
                
            } //scnr.close();
        }
    }
}
```

File Service Class method

```
   public static ArrayList<SalableProduct> loadProductsFromFile(String filename) {

        
            ArrayList<SalableProduct> products = new ArrayList<SalableProduct>();
            try {
                File file = new File(filename);
                Scanner scnr = new Scanner(file);
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                
                while (scnr.hasNext()) {
                    String json = scnr.nextLine();
                    SalableProduct product = objectMapper.readValue(json, SalableProduct.class);
                    products.add(product);
                }
                scnr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } return products;
        }
```

I have tried running my program in debug mode and watch all the steps closely but have not had any luck. It works when I hardcode/manually enter the inventory but hasn't since I implemented the JSON file and methods to call it.

Here is the SalableProduct Class

```
    public class SalableProduct {
        /**
         * placeholder for items to sell in store
         */
        private String name;
        private String description;
        private double price;
        private int qty;
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
    
        public SalableProduct(String name, String description, double price, int qty) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
            this.price = price;
            this.qty = qty;
        }
    
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
    
        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
    
        public void setPrice(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
    
        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    
        public int getQty() {
            return qty;
        }
        
        public void setQty(int qty) {
            this.qty = qty;
        }
    
        public SalableProduct() {
            name = "";
            description = "";
            price = 0;
            qty = 0;
        }
    }
```

```
Here is my JSON file
```

```
    {"name":"Goji Berry","description":"bright orange-red berry that comes from a shrub native to Asia","price":8.32,"qty":496}
    {"name":"Elixir","description":"Potion that grants eternal life","price":3469.00,"qty":4}
    {"name":"Kabuto","description":"Ancient Japanese war helmet","price":999.99,"qty":43}
    {"name":"Polished Tomahawk","description":"Benjamin Martins Tomahawk","price":567.00,"qty":1}
    {"name":"Heater Shield","description":"Used in the Middle Ages by knights and soldiers","price":269.00,"qty":57}
    {"name":"Katana","description":"single-edged sword used by Japanese samurai","price":4469.00,"qty":21}
```

Here is the displaySalable products

```
        for (SalableProduct product : products) {
            System.out.println(product.getName() + " - " + product.getDescription() + " - Price: $" + product.getPrice()
                    + " - Quantity: " + product.getQty());
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it's failing on the _JSON_ mapping, then there is either a syntax error in the _JSON_, or there is a discrepancy with the _SalableProduct_ abstraction.  Can you post a segment of the _JSON_ and the code for the _SalableProduct_ class?

Comment: I have added what you requested. I am not receiving any errors when I execute my code in eclipse. It will only print my options for the different cases and when I select 1 or 2 it doesn't show any inventory.

Comment: Alright, so in _purchaseProducts_ you shouldn't need _"scnr.nextLine(); // Consume newline character"_, since you have already produced a new-line from the options output.

Comment: So I remarked it out and it still isn't showing my available products to purchase. Now when I enter "2" it won't even let me put an input. The reason that scnr.nextLine(); is there is for user input on what they want to purchase when option "2" is selected. option "1" should only display what is in the JSON file.

Comment: Yes, although you have another _nextLine_ call on the following line, _"String productName = scnr.nextLine();"_.  So, the first _nextLine_ will skip over any input, thus, _productName_ will not contain a value, or, will be an empty _string_, rather.

Comment: But I am needing that scnr.nextLine(); so that the user can input the product that the user wants to purchase.

Either way my program still will not show products for sale when "1" is input into the console.

Comment: So, for that we'll need the _InventoryManager_ class code.  Well, specifically, the _displaySalableProducts_ method.

Comment: I have added the salableProducts method from InventoryManager class

Comment: Reilas, were you able to review my code to see what the issue is?

Comment: Unfortunately, not without the code.

Comment: Do you need the whole InventoryManager class or displaySalableProducts method? I put the method at the bottom of the main comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was residing in my Product class, I had previously had  and was using SalableProduct as my super class but Product needed to be on its own. I also had to add generics to all of my classes. So now my code is this.

```
package app;

public class Product <T extends SalableProduct> {

    public Product(String name, String description, double price, int qty) {    
    }
}
```

I also added this line to my StoreFront class in the main method.

```
inventoryManager.initializeInventoryFromFile("inventory.json");
```

here is my method for initializeInventoryFromFile method in my InventoryManager class.

```
    public void initializeInventoryFromFile(String filename) {
         ArrayList<T> products = (ArrayList<T>) FileService.loadProductsFromFile("inventory.json");

        for (T product : products) {
            addProduct( product);
            
        }
    }
```